# My updated SMS Receiver doesn't work Android

Tags: android, sms

hi :) i'm working with SMS in android. i'm having problem with my sms receiver class. when i run my app for the first time on emulator, it works as i've programmed it to work. but when every time i run the app again, it doesn't work as i updated it to work. i'm stuck for last 2 days. can somebody plz guide me or provide some help. my basic receiver class is:

```
public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String Sender = null;
    String str = "";
    SmsMessage [] msgs = null;
    if(bundle != null)
    {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
        {

            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            Sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str = "SMS From: " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += ":";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }
        //Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, Sender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

in above code, i've commented the toast that shows the msg, and tried to display the toast that shows the sender's number. but still it shows the new msg text. that's weird.

here's my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pingpongsmsremote"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.SMSScheduler"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_smsscheduler" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.FilterSMS"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_filter_sms" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.SMSRemote"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_smsremote" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.SendSms"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_send_sms" >
    </activity>
</application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show where you're registering the receiver? Is it being registered in the manifest file or in an activity?

Comment: @akhalsa yea, i'm gona edit my question text with manifest. have a look at it

Comment: @akhalsa i've edited my question along with Manifest file. can you plz now have a look on it and tell where the problem is? thanks :)

Comment: Wait... I don't see where you're registering your receiver in the manifest? Are you registering it in an activity or am i missing something here?

Comment: @akhalsa .. i thought i'm working with broadcast receiver, so still i would have to make it registered with some activity or what? if so, plz guide me

Comment: See my answer below. You need to register your receiver with the context somehow to pickup broadcasts with a certain name. In this case "android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED". You can do this dynamically from an activity, but its probably easier to just add a few lines to the manifest like I show in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like maybe you forgot to register the receiver? You need a line like this in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="SMSreceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

To see it in a full manifest example would look like this:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pingpongsmsremote"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.SMSScheduler"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_smsscheduler" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.FilterSMS"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_filter_sms" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.SMSRemote"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_smsremote" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pingpongsmsremote.SendSms"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_send_sms" >
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="SMSreceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: unless you're registering somewhere in an activity?

Comment: fine. i'm sure i'm missing something in my manifest. but i don't know where to add this? and that, there's no such tag named "receiver" exists :| .. plz help me

Comment: take a look at the manifests in this tutorial:  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: it just goes in the manifest inside the application tag, just like you can see there in the first example. There is definitely a tag called receiver for manifests, its either complaining because you're putting it in the wrong spot or have a typo :)